# In LiteDB how do I Query a subdocument?

Tags: c#, subdocument, litedb

Given the following Person Class document and its BookBag[] subdocument Array:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public BookBag[] Bags { get; set; }
  
  public class BookBag
  {
    //contains books of various titles
    public string[] Content { get; set; }
  }
}
```

How do I get all Persons that have a BookBag with a book title string that contains the word "Apple" in **LiteDB**?

I've tried the following statement in my using database block, but failed:

`col.Find("SUBSTRING($.Bags[*].Content, 0, 1) = 'Apple'")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I just figured out my own dilemma. The correct statement is:

`col.Find("$.Bags[*].Content[*] ANY LIKE '%Apple%'");`

Please correct me if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Yes, you're right!! Can mark as correct ;)